# Problemas con encriptación en Kotlin (SHA-256)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, encriptación, sha256

Estoy intentando encriptar y desencriptar cadenas de caracteres a través de unas funciones en Kotlin. El problema es que a la hora de desencriptar, no lo hace bien y no sé el motivo. Una función se encarga de encriptar pasándole el mensaje y una contraseña de usuario y otra función recibe los mismos parámetros y lo desencripta. La última función genera una clase tipo SHA-256 a través de la contraseña de usuario que recibe. Estas con las tres funciones que tengo.

```
/**
     * Funcion que encripta el mensaje y lo devuelve desencriptado
     */
    fun desencriptar(datos: String, pass: String): String{
        //
        var secretKey: SecretKeySpec = generateKey(pass)
        var cipher: Cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES")
        // Modo desencriptación
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey)

        // Array de bytes con datos descodificados
        var datosDescodificados: ByteArray = Base64.decode(datos, Base64.DEFAULT)
        // Array de bytes con datos desencriptados
        var datosDesenciptadosByte: ByteArray = cipher.doFinal(datosDescodificados)
        // Datos desencriptados en String
        var datosDesencriptadosString = String(datosDesenciptadosByte)

        return datosDesencriptadosString
    }

    /**
     * Función que encripta el mensaje y lo devuelve encriptado
     */
    fun encriptar(datos: String, pass: String): String {
        //
        var secretKey: SecretKeySpec = generateKey(pass)
        // Algoritmo de encriptación tipo AES
        var cipher: Cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES")
        // Modo encriptación
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey)

        // Array de datos en bytes
        var datosEncriptadosBytes: ByteArray = cipher.doFinal(datos.toByteArray())
        // Devolverlo en Base64 y se convierte a String
        var datosEncriptadosString: String = Base64.encodeToString(datosEncriptadosBytes, Base64.DEFAULT)

        return datosEncriptadosString
    }

    /**
     * Genera una clave de tipo Sha-256 pasándole una contraseña de usuario
     */
    fun generateKey (pass: String): SecretKeySpec {
        // Genera el algoritmo seguro
        val sha: MessageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256")
        // Pasar la clave a byte con el estándar UTF-8 en un array de bytes
        var key: ByteArray = pass.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8)
        // Llamamos al método digest que completa el cálculo del hash
        key = sha.digest(key)
        // Usamos estándar AES
        val secretKey = SecretKeySpec(key, "AES")

        return secretKey
    }
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola PacoPepe, trata de no repetir preguntas, no te desesperes, voy a agregar una respuesta, saludos. Tienes un ejemplo de la cadena de caracteres que provoca el problema? tu código debe funcionar, agregue una respuesta como usarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con respecto a lo que deseas:

> La última función genera una clase tipo SHA-256 a través de la
> contraseña de usuario que recibe.

Si generas un [SHA-256](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/9004655?hl=es-419) y quieres obtener lo que se guardo esto no es posible, lo que sucede es que SHA es un Hash, no un valor encriptado. SHA es unidireccional y únicamente se usa para validación no para encriptar o cifrar. Revisa
[Android Criptografía](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/cryptography?hl=es-419) .

En el caso de tu código el algoritmo que usas es `AES` que es lo que realizas aquí:

```
  fun encriptar(datos: String, pass: String): String {
        var secretKey: SecretKeySpec = generateKey(pass)
        var cipher: Cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES")
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey)    
        var datosEncriptadosBytes: ByteArray = cipher.doFinal(datos.toByteArray())
        var datosEncriptadosString: String = Base64.encodeToString(datosEncriptadosBytes, Base64.DEFAULT)    
        return datosEncriptadosString
    }
```

Revisando las funciones funcionan correctamente por ejemplo para encriptar usas:

```
val datosEncriptados = encriptar("Puisor meu!", "Totita12!") 
println(datosEncriptados)
```

Donde el primer parámetro es la cadena a encriptar y el segundo la clave, se obtendría como valor:

```
HysY7A/KFZ+d8GljSziNGA==
```

Para desencriptar si usas el valor anterior:

```
 val datosEncriptados = "HysY7A/KFZ+d8GljSziNGA=="
 val datosDesEncriptados = desencriptar(datosEncriptados, "Totita12!")
 println(datosDesEncriptados)
```

se obtendría la cadena original.

```
Puisor meu!
```