# Error InvocationTargetException al descifrar una cadena de texto de una tabla SQLite

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, cifrado, sha256

Estoy intentando cifrar y descifrar el contenido de una base de datos. El cifrar lo hace bien, pero al descifrar me da un error de tipo java.lang.InvocationTargetException. Estos son las funciones que cifran y descifran. El error me salta nada más llamar a la función descodificarDatos(). En el código marco dónde me da se produce el error dentro de esta función.

```
    /**
     * Función que descodifica el mensaje y lo devuelve
     */
    fun descodificarDatos(datos: String, pass: String): String{
        //
        var secretKey: SecretKeySpec = generateKey(pass)
        var cipher: Cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES")
        // Modo desencriptación
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey)

        // Array de bytes con datos descodificados
        var datosDescodificados: ByteArray = Base64.decode(datos, Base64.DEFAULT)
        // Array de bytes con datos desencriptados
        // AVISO: En la siguiete instrucción se produce el error
        var datosDesenciptadosByte: ByteArray = cipher.doFinal(datosDescodificados)
        // Datos desencriptados en String
        var datosDesencriptadosString = String(datosDesenciptadosByte)

        return datosDesencriptadosString
    }

    /**
     * Función que encripta el mensaje y lo devuelve encriptado
     */
    fun codificarDatos(datos: String, pass: String): String {
        //
        var secretKey: SecretKeySpec = generateKey(pass)
        // Algoritmo de encriptación tipo AES
        var cipher: Cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES")
        // Modo encriptación
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey)

        // Array de datos en bytes
        var datosEncriptadosBytes: ByteArray = cipher.doFinal(datos.toByteArray())
        // Devolverlo en Base64 y se convierte a String
        var datosEncriptadosString: String = Base64.encodeToString(datosEncriptadosBytes, Base64.DEFAULT)

        return datosEncriptadosString
    }
```

Y esta es la función que recoge los datos de la base de datos SQLite y lo encripta. La idea es que lea los datos de la base de datos ya codificados y los guarde descodificados mediante un UPDATE

```
private fun descodificarTabla(){
        // Conexión con la base de datos
        val admin = DBHelper(this)
        val db = admin.writableDatabase
        // Cursor donde se almacenan datos
        val cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from Preguntas Order by Id desc", null)

        // Limpiamos la lista en caso de que contenga algo
        listaPreguntas.clear()

        // Se van convirtiendo y descodificando los datos de la base de datos a objetos y se añaden a la lista
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                val id: Int = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Id").toInt()).toInt()
                val pregunta: String = descodificarDatos(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Pregunta").toInt()), password)
                val respuesta1: String = descodificarDatos(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Respuesta1").toInt()), password)
                val respuesta2: String = descodificarDatos(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Respuesta2").toInt()), password)
                val respuesta3: String = descodificarDatos(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Respuesta3").toInt()), password)
                val respuesta4: String = descodificarDatos(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Respuesta4").toInt()), password)
                val respuestaCorrecta: String = descodificarDatos(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("RespuestaCorrecta").toInt()), password)

                val preguntaObject: Preguntas = Preguntas(id, pregunta, respuesta1, respuesta2, respuesta3, respuesta4, respuestaCorrecta)

                db.execSQL("UPDATE preguntas SET Pregunta = '" + preguntaObject.pregunta + "', Respuesta1 = '" + preguntaObject.respuesta1 + "', Respuesta2 = '" +
                        preguntaObject.respuesta2 + "', Respuesta3 = '" + preguntaObject.respuesta3 + "', Respuesta4 = '" + preguntaObject.respuesta4 + "' WHERE Id = " + preguntaObject.id)

                listaPreguntas.add(preguntaObject)

            }while(cursor.moveToNext())
        }

        // Notificar al adapter que hay cambios
        if (listaPreguntas.size > 0){
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

        // Cerramos conexiones
        cursor.close()
        db.close()
    }
```

Este es el error que me da completo

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.sqlite, PID: 12452
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:502)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
 Caused by: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: last block incomplete in decryption
    at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher.engineDoFinal(BaseBlockCipher.java:1220)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2055)
    at com.example.sqlite.MainActivity.descodificarDatos(MainActivity.kt:220)
    at com.example.sqlite.MainActivity.descodificarTabla(MainActivity.kt:176)
    at com.example.sqlite.MainActivity.onCreate$lambda-2(MainActivity.kt:64)
    at com.example.sqlite.MainActivity.$r8$lambda$vAnFxsRHG3QEAwNR77jEEi4diaE(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.example.sqlite.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
    at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Comment: Hola, es lo mismo de esta pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/489423/problemas-con-encriptaci%c3%b3n-en-kotlin-sha-256 ? Agrega el error completo para tener mas detalles.

Comment: Hola. Borré esa pregunta pero no sé porque no lo ha hecho. He agregado el error al completo. Gracias.

Comment: De todas formas resulta que ahora me da ese error al intentar descifrar y no entiendo muy bien porque.

Comment: Hola PacoPepe, gracias, veo que el error en realidad es : Caused by: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: last block incomplete in decryption lo reviso para dar una soluciòn

Comment: Gracias, espero puedas ayudarme. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo he arreglado. Al final el error no estaba en la función. Hay que ir a donde se llama la función descodificarTabla() y colocar las contantes así

```
                val id: Int = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Id").toInt()).toInt()
                val pregunta: String = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Pregunta").toInt())
                val respuesta1: String = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Respuesta1").toInt())
                val respuesta2: String = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Respuesta2").toInt())
                val respuesta3: String = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Respuesta3").toInt())
                val respuesta4: String = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Respuesta4").toInt())
                val respuestaCorrecta: String = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("RespuestaCorrecta").toInt())
```

Y luego crear un objeto de preguntas llamando a la función descodificarDatos para descodificar las constantes a la vez que se crea el objeto. De la siguiente forma:

```
                        val preguntaObject: Preguntas = Preguntas(id, descodificarDatos(pregunta, password), descodificarDatos(respuesta1, password),
                        descodificarDatos(respuesta2, password), descodificarDatos(respuesta3, password), descodificarDatos(respuesta4, password),
                        descodificarDatos(respuestaCorrecta, password))
```

Así no da el error.